# Python Fabric: How to execute command in screen session

Tags: python, fabric, devops, gnu-screen

I am doing following:

```
with settings(host_string=h['server'].rstrip('\n').strip(), warn_only=True):
                # run("hostname -f")
                with cd('path/folder'):
                  # Check for Screen session, if none, create one otherwise screen -d -r
                    result = run('screen -r')
                    output_stdout = result.stdout.strip()
                    print('OUTPUT = ' + output_stdout)
                    if 'There is a screen on' in output_stdout:
                        run('screen -d -r')
                        run('exit')
                    elif 'There is no screen to be resumed' in output_stdout:
                        run('screen')
                        # Checking screen stats
                        run('screen -r')
                       # Generate Link File
                       run('python3 file.py ' + str(start) + ' ' + str(end))
```

What's been happening that once screen is on, fabric gets into an infinite loop and never comes out.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing `screen -Rd`:

```
-d -R   Reattach a session and if necessary detach or even create it first.
```